# Heap Block Error While Reading File Contents

Tags: c, heap-memory, fread

I am attempting to write a program which reads the letters "A, B, C, D, E" from a file, notes all instances of these characters, and ignores any characters in between the greater than and less than signs,  "< and >". Although the file seems to have been opened correctly, the for loop located in findCommonAnswers() seems to access values that are protected or non-existent. Windows provides the exception code c0000005 and the GNU debugger tells me that "A Heap block at 0xXXXXX has been modified at 0xXXXXX+1 past request size of 6". The number 6 has been constant in each debugging. The current output of the code is "-1.#IND", in previous versions it returned a zero for all items except the constant "probabilityArrayLength". If anyone could give me any insight of the nature of the error, it would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
...
...
int fsize(FILE *fp)
{

    int prev = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,prev,SEEK_SET);    
  return sz;
}

double* findCommonAnswerChoices( )
{
  FILE *data;  
  data = fopen( "F:\\COMP_SCI\\APCalculusBCMultipleChoiceResults.txt", "r" );

int bufferSize = fsize( data ), totalAnswers = 0, instanceOfA = 0, instanceOfB = 0,
instanceOfC = 0, instanceOfD = 0, instanceOfE = 0, probabilityArrayLength =6,    bytesRead = 0;
int j = 0 , k;

double probOfA = 0.0, probOfB = 0.0, probOfC = 0.0, probOfD = 0.0, probOfE = 0.0;
double* probabilities = (double*)malloc( probabilityArrayLength*(sizeof(double)) );

char answers[bufferSize];

if( data==NULL )
{
    printf( "%d %s %d \n",bufferSize, " ", sizeof(data) );
    printf( "Not Enough Memory" );

}
else
{
    bytesRead = fread( answers, 0, bufferSize, data );
}


for( j = 0; j<bytesRead; j++ )
{
    if( answers[j]=='<' )
    {
        do
        {
            j++;
        }
        while( answers[j]!='>' );
    }

    switch( answers[j] )
    {

        case 'A':
            instanceOfA++;
            break;

        case 'B':
            instanceOfB++;
            break;

        case 'C':
            instanceOfC++;
            break;

        case 'D':
            instanceOfD++;
            break;

        case 'E':
            instanceOfE++;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

fclose(data);

totalAnswers = ( instanceOfA+instanceOfB+instanceOfC+instanceOfD+instanceOfE );
probOfA = ( (double)instanceOfA/(double)totalAnswers );
probOfB = ( (double)instanceOfB/(double)totalAnswers );
probOfC = ( (double)instanceOfC/(double)totalAnswers );
probOfD = ( (double)instanceOfD/(double)totalAnswers );
probOfE = ( (double)instanceOfE/(double)totalAnswers );

probabilities[0] = (double)probabilityArrayLength;
probabilities[1] = probOfA;
probabilities[2] = probOfB;
probabilities[3] = probOfC;
probabilities[4] = probOfD;
probabilities[5] = probOfE;

return probabilities;
}

 int main()
 {
double* something = findCommonAnswerChoices();
int size = (int)something[0];
int p;

for( p = 0; p<size; p++  )
{
    printf( "%g \n", something[p] );
}
free( something );
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double* probabilities = (double*)malloc( probabilityArrayLength );
```

this allocates 6 bytes, which are not enough to store 6 doubles. It should be:

```
double* probabilities = malloc(probabilityArrayLength*sizeof(double));
```

And you can omit the cast, in C you can assign a `void*` to any kind of pointer.

Your `fsize` method has an error too, you are seeking to the end to get the length of the file but you are not seeking back to beginning afterwards with `fseek(fp, SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: I have changed those lines of codes. The program now executes normally, however the output is still "-1.#IND". I am not sure precisely what this means, but does it possibly mean that there is a problem with the arithmetic at the end of findCommonAnswersChoices?

Comment: Actually with `fread( answers, 0, bufferSize, data )` you are not really reading anything since size of elements is 0. You should fix it according to what you are reading.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. After I made that last change, the program now compiles, and runs to produce the correct values.